# Amazon S3 sync millions of files to local for incremental backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

Trying to sync a large (millions of files) S3 bucket from cloud to local storage seems to be troublesome process for most S3 tools, as virtually everything I've seen so far uses [GET Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) operation, patiently getting the whole list of files in bucket, then diffing it against a list local of files, then performing the actual file transfer.

This looks extremely unoptimal. For example, if one could list files in a bucket that were created / changed since the given date, this could be done quickly, as list of files to be transferred would include just a handful, not millions.

However, given that [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974112/amazon-s3-syncing-modified-date-vs-uploaded-date) is still true, it's not possible to do so in S3 API.

Are there any other approaches to do periodic incremental backups of a given large S3 bucket?

Comment: You can set up an index for your bucket. e.g. a Dynamo table that tracks everything you put into the bucket, which you can index by timestamp, content-hash, etc.

Answer (score 2):

On AWS S3 you can configure event notifications (Ex: `s3:ObjectCreated:*`). To request notification when an object is created. It supports `SNS`, `SQS` and `Lambda` services. So you can have an application that listens on the event and updates the statistics. You may also want to ad timestamp as part of the statistic. Then just "query" the result for a certain period of time and you will get your delta.

Comment: I was going to recommend this :).